# Interactive shell in Docker image with Amazon ECS with `aws ecs run-task` followed by `aws ecs execute-command`

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I would like to launch an interactive shell into a public Docker image on my AWS ECS/Fargate cluster to run network/connectivity tests from inside the cluster.

It seems the official way to do this is with `aws ecs run-task` followed by `aws ecs execute-command` [1][2]

I'd like to use existing, public Docker Hub images rather than build custom images if possible.

If I run do `run-task` with no command or the default command, the task exits and `execute-command` won't work on an exited task.

```
"Essential container in task exited"
```

If I set a Docker command of `sleep 10000`, I get:

```
"CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"sleep 10000\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown",
```

Ideally, run-task and execute-command would be combined in one step. I don't want a background task running indefinitely, I want a shell to run a few commands interactively, that is cleaned up when I'm finished. How would I achieve this?

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: I am confused. If you only need/want to run a command and then exit why would you want to launch the task and then `ecs exec` into it? The proper pattern would be to launch the command overriding the `entrypoint`/`command` with the command you want to use no?

Comment: So, I want to run an interactive shell command, not just any command. Interactive shell support is a new feature, most ECS isn't designed for that. I can specify or override entrypoint / command in the ECS TaskDefinition. I need to use `execute-command` to get an interactive shell (AFAIK).

Comment: So if you need to interact with the shell then yes you need to use `ecs exec`. The suggestion Mark is providing seems to be a good way to achieve it.

Comment: Your main question is already answered below, but the error message you got when trying to run `sleep 10000` is because you're unintentionally asking to run a binary literally called "sleep 10000".  Arguments are accepted as an array, so the easiest way to do this would be to specify `"sleep", "10000"` instead of `"sleep 10000"`.  If you also end up wanting to run a little shell script, you can use something like `"sh", "-c", "sleep 10000"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was finally able to get a container to sit "idle" with the following command inside the Task Definition:

```
"tail", "-F", "/dev/null"
```

Then I could connect in with an interactive `execute-command`.

Comment: `"sleep", "inf"` is another good way to do this.